# Problem from trignometry

Tags: trigonometry

If $3\cot A=4$ then prove that $\dfrac{1-\tan^2 A}{1+\tan^2 A}=\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A$

Comment: I think your post was not correct, because, $\frac {1-\tan^2 A}{1+\tan^2 A }=\frac {\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A}{\cos^2 A+\sin^2 A}$. here, the previous condition is needless. I think your qoustion was another.

Comment: From this site's "How to ask" ( math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask ):  "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? ... Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs."  So, what did you find and how did it not meet your needs?

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A= \cos^2(A) (1- \tan^2(A))=\frac{1-\tan^2(A)}{\sec^2(A)}=\frac{1-\tan^2(A)}{1+\tan^2(A)}$$

Answer (score 0):

The equality you have to prove is always true if $\tan A$ is defined of course. Just use the fact that $\tan A=\dfrac{\sin A}{\cos A}$ to simplify the left side of the equality and get the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a triangle with legs' lengths equals to 3 and 4. The side across from A must be 3( cosA = 3/4).... Use Pythagoras to determine the hypotenuse (5)...

Left side = [1-(3/4)^2] / [1 + (3/2)^2] = 7/25

Right side = [(4/5)^2] - [(3/5)^2] = 7/25

Left side = right side